# R: Speed up combine(paste or paste0) operation for 39 millions rows and two columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a DT (data.table), which include 39-million rows and two columns, for exmaple `cola` and `colb`, and I want to add a new column named `colc`, which is `DT[,`:=`(colc = paste(cola, colb, sep="-"))`, but the speed is a little slow.

Do you have an alternative way to speed up this operation?

Comment: how slow is a little slow? (What speed, on what hardware?) I wouldn't be surprised if you were pretty much maxed out.  Can you parallelize it?

Comment: use `DT[,`:=`(colc = paste0(cola, colb))`, it spent about 393 seconds on Linux platform. I do not consider parallize it. In addtion, If I do 'plus' operation `DT[,`:=`(colc = cola + colb)`, it is fast (since cola and colb are numeric), but some colc values will be equal by do plus operation, so I consider use the paste function to put them together, make sure each of them are different.

Comment: If combos `(cola,colb)` repeat a lot, a `by` statement should speed it up. To check how much repetition you have, you could look at `DT[,.N,by='cola,colb'][,hist(N)]` (or whatever summarization command if not `hist`).

Comment: Thanks Frank. I never notice by='cola,colb' before. It is good `by` this two columns.

Comment: `cola` and `colb` are numeric? are they both single digits? will something along the lines of `DT[,colc:=10*cola+colb]` (as long as `colb` always has the same number of digits, you should be able to do s.t. along these lines)

Comment: sometime, cola and colb can be character class. So I think Frank gave me a hint, `by` the two cola and colb, which is the same what I would like to do `colc <- paste0(cola, colb); DT[, , by = colc]`.

Comment: Or, find the largest number of digits in `colb` (say n), then do:
`dt[,colc:=10^(n+1)*cola+10^n+colb]`. this will force all of `colb` to the same length & "paste" `cola` to the left.

Comment: Thanks MichaelChirico. It is a good trick to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Frank suggested, using `by = 'cola,colb'`, my original problem can be solved in this way and do not need add the additional column.

Comment: I think you might find the new [HTML vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) quite useful.